# encrypt data in T-SQL using DES (not triple) algorithm

Tags: t-sql, des

I need to encode some strings using DES (not triple DES - I know that there is many articles describing how to use NCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE command). I have key and IV.
How I can do it using T-SQL? Is there any ready to use procedure or function?

Answer (score 0):

Ripped from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  I haven't tested this, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345262%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) page lists all of the encryption types and DES appears to be one of them.

```
--If there is no master key, create one now. 
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY 
    PASSWORD = '23987hxJKL969#ghf0%94467GRkjg5k3fd117r$$#1946kcj$n44nhdlj'
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE HumanResources037
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Employee Social Security Numbers';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
    WITH ALGORITHM = DES
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;
GO

-- Open the symmetric key with which to encrypt the data.
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;

-- Encrypt the value 
SET @encrypted = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), '555-77-4444');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's description for SQL Server 2005. In older version, I there is no sys.symmetric_keys table. Is there any other methods to accomplish this task?

Comment: @matandked - The only encryption methods I'm aware of in SQL 2000 is PWDENCRYPT() and PWDCOMPARE()